# Prove that G admits a composition series of length $a_1 + · · · + a_k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let be G an abelian group of order $n = p^{a1}_1· · · p^{ak}_k$
where $p_i$ is prime such that $p_i\neq p_j$ if $i \neq j$. Prove that G admits a composition series of length $a_1 + · · · + a_k$.

My path

Let $n = p^{a1}_1· · · p^{ak}_k$ be the order of the Abelian group $G$, with $p_i$’s distinct primes.
By Sylow’s theorem it follows that $G$ has exacly one Sylow $p$−subgroup for each of the $k$
distinct primes $p_i$. Consequently $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow $p$−subgroups. [We
call the Sylow $p$−subgroups the $p$− primary parts of G.] It remains to show that an
Abelian $p$−group (corresponding to a $p$−primary part of $G$) is the direct product of cyclic
groups.

But I'm not sure if this path is correct. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Sylow theorems here; you can show that a finite abelian group is a finite direct product of $p$-primary parts using the Chinese remainder theorem.

But actually you don't even need this. The argument is just by strong induction on $n$. Let $H$ be any maximal proper subgroup and show that $G/H$ has order a prime. Then apply the same argument to $H$, inductively. We don't even need the full strength of the assumption that $G$ is abelian; this argument will show that the result is still true if we just assume that $G$ is solvable, although here we need $H$ to be a maximal proper normal subgroup. Moreover this result is sharp: a finite group of order $\prod p_i^{a_i}$ admits a composition series of length $\sum a_i$ iff it is solvable.

This argument does not require knowing in advance that composition series exist, and can be used to prove that finite groups have composition series. If you already know that fact, then show that every composition series of a finite solvable group of order $\prod p_i^{a_i}$ must have length $\sum a_i$.